# with as and premature file closure

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

I have a python function that contains the following code:

```
with open(modelfilepath, "rb") as modelfile, open(vcffilepath, "rb") as vcffile:
    for row in gtf_getrow(modelfile):
        print row
        #add features as appropriate
        if row["feature"] == "transcript":
            addfeature(some args...)
        if row["feature"] == "exon":
            addfeature(some other args..., vcffile=vcffile)
```

Execution of the addfeature() function passes through several functions before returning to the `for` loop. In the "exon" case, the `vcffile` object is passed as an argument to successive functions which eventually write to the `vcffile`.

The problem is that after a few iterations, the `vcffile` object seems to close spontaneously, which crashes the program. If I hardcode the function that uses `vcffile` to access the filename directly, the problem does not occur, but this seems like an undesirable solution since it removes control of the file from the with block. Nor do I want to have to open and close the file each time I access it, since this program is parsing hundreds of megabytes worth of tabular data. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: This code is fine; the problem must lie elsewhere. What is your OS and file system? Is the file across the network?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you show. Can you come up with an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not accidentally closing the file yourself in one of the nested functions?

Comment: Put some debug statements in to see when the file is open, and when it closes.

Comment: Thanks for your eyes. I did attach a debugger and stepped up and down the stack on the last pre-crash op a few times, but never managed to figure out quite what was going on. It actually was crashing in the gzip module. But I noticed that I was creating a reader object from the vcffile object inside a loop rather than outside, resulting in repeated calls to the __init__, so once I moved that out of the loop the problem went away.